Заменить часть данных в формуле google spreadsheet
Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо найти и заменить часть формулы —
1 формула:
=HR!A2
на
2 формула:
=HR!A3
у 1 формулы диапазон от A до M
поэтому замена нужна в этом диапазоне, а лучше просто цифру 2 на 3
что-то типа =HR!*2 на =HR!*3
Подскажите, как это проще всего сделать?
С точкой он все формулы на листе находит, но меняет так же на формулу с точкой


Если вам нужна замена только цифры, в поле "Заменить на" поставьте нужный вам вариант формулы, в данном случае =HR!A3

Решение

Если есть возможность выделить диапазон только с Вашими формулами =HR!*2, то выделяете и заменяете 2 на 3 с включенной галочкой "поиск по формулам".

Если формулы разбросаны по всему листу, тогда выделяете всё, включаете галочки "поиск с использованием регулярных выражений" и "Поиск по формулам"
Найти:  =HR!(\w+)2
Заменить: =HR!$13


Пояснение. $1 в поле замены означает первое скобочное выражение из поля найти.
